# Set Data Driven Scale from Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arccatalog, data-driven-pages

Is there a way to set the data driven scale from arcpy? Looking at the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000030000000) for the `DataDrivenPages` class, it doesn't seem to be accessible from outside of ArcMap. The script I run within the current map document exports the maps as jpgs based on the `Name` and `Page Number` fields I set, and at the `Data Driven Scale` I specified. When I put the same script into a model (with the necessary adjustments made) and run it from ArcCatalog, I get the same result, except the maps are now at `Best Fit` scale, which is the default for data driven pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that the correct scale is used (in my case, the scales are valued stored in a field `scale_field`), the following code is added to the `for` loop which exports all the maps (the input document must have Data Driven Pages Enabled):

```
#some code here
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(inputMapDoc)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0] #using the 1st data frame
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
      mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
      df.scale = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue(scale_field)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script on a stored mxd you can set the scale properties in the extent tab of the data driven page setup. You can either use your current scale or use a field from the index layer that contains scale values.

[image]

Comment: The Data Driven Scale is set and stored within the mxd, so in theory it should be able to export it from the model at that specified scale. I've gotten a response from ESRI, so I'm going to try that now and post back here.

Comment: I would be really interested in a solution to this as well. My key issue is when the scales change within a DDP setup and you get wierd scale bars like 1cm=2.35Km instead of 1cm=2km or whatever and I have had to create separate mxd's for each scale. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23375/arcpy-ddp-alter-graticule-logically-in-varying-map-scales

Comment: @GeorgeC I've added the solution which worked for me, but I'm not sure if it will solve your problem. Have you tried first extracting the scales at `Best Fit` and storing these values in the field, then using my answer below to set the map scale?