# Can I automate using different reference grids in a data driven map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, layouts

I am trying to create a data driven layout that includes an overview map, at 1:15000, and a number of inset maps, at 1:4000.  I need to have two reference grids for the layout since the map scales are different and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to switch between the two grids automatically.  Right now I am manually switching between the reference grids and then manually cycling through the pages to print them out.  Is this something that can be automated through the data driven pages UI or would I need to do some scripting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArcPy / DDP - alter graticule logically in varying map scales](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23375/arcpy-ddp-alter-graticule-logically-in-varying-map-scales)

Comment: Can you perhaps edit your question to describe what you are doing in a little more detail using pictures, please?  I think you will come up against the issue highlighted in the duplicate that I have suggested but more details will help to clarify whether that is the case.