# Placing data driven dynamic text in data view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I am using data driven text in some of my map label elements, but I would like those text boxes to move with the data as opposed to being placed in relation to the layout view.  In this way if I have two areas to show on two different maps but each have unique labeling elements around them, I do not have to shift around the dynamic text boxes when I output one map or the other.

Is this possible?  If so, how do you do it?

Comment: It isn't exactly what you want to do, but this may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169781/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-scale-bar-interval-and-other-settings-on-individual

Comment: it's not possible without some scripting.  You'll need to create named text elements that you can shift on and off the page using arcpy.  Procedure would be to create all text elements, find the x/y of the position each element needs to move to and what page it needs to be on, incorporate into data driven page export script.

Comment: Are you able to include a picture that illustrates what you want to do, please?  Otherwise, I think the comment by @jbalk should be made into an answer.