# Using Data Driven text in legends?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, data-driven-pages

I am trying to use an attribute of the data driven page in the legend. I am labeling a polygon layer set to only show if it matches the ddp through a Page Definition.

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I'm trying:

[image]

I'm using ArcMap 10.5 with data driven pages enabled.

Has anyone tried doing this before?

I'd like to stay within ArcMap for ease of passing this to someone less comfortable with ArcPy, but would be open to a scripting solution also.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, *but* you can use arcpy to move graphic elements around in a layout. So you could create a separate text element for each individual DDP page, then use arcpy to move them onto and off of the layout for each consecutive page. I don't know how to do that though, which is why this is a comment. See the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169781/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-scale-bar-interval-and-other-settings-on-individual)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a work around that I figured out that works because I don't have a ton of ddp. I symbolized the layer by category and then set the symbology as the same for every category and enabled page definitions to match that of the index layer. This allowed me to have a different label for each feature. Then in the legend dialogue box, I selected the option to only show classes that are visible in the current map extent and use current index feature as the map extent.
[image: Almost DDP legend]

Comment: That's what I do. I think there is a better *if you own the Production Mapping license*

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap) you can add 'legend' dataframe with N identical rectangles and use page definition query and labeling to show one of interest:

[image]