# Placing data frame as inset on only one page of Data Driven Pages map book?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, data-frame, map-book

I am using data driven pages to make a 5-page mapbook of an area. There is also one far-away site that I wanted to include an inset of on the first page of my mapbook (near to where it is). However, I don't want that inset map to be in the following four pages.

How do I make a data frame appear in only one page of my data-driven map book and not in all of the pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change the scale bar interval and other settings on individual Data-Driven Pages?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169781/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-scale-bar-interval-and-other-settings-on-individual). Basically you will use arcpy to move that inset map around within your layout, moving it within the visible page extents for the first page of the mapbook, then outside the page extents for the other pages. You can use this trick with legends, scale bars, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you may be planning to export your Data Driven Pages enabled map to PDF format, I think the simplest way to do this would be to:

1. Add your Inset data frame to your Layout view and Export to PDF for just that one page
2. Move your Inset data frame off the page and Export to PDF for the other four pages
3. Use a few lines of `arcpy.mapping` code to append your two PDF files into a single one.  There is a good sample on how to do this in the [Help for the PDFDocument class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/pdfdocument-class.htm#C_GUID-36E69E05-DD9D-4019-8D1D-2664828EF6BB).