# How to create dynamic (depend on scale) coordinates grid in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, scale, grids-graticules, dynamic

I am working in ArcGIS Desktop. I want to dynamicly change my coordinate grid in layout view depending on map's scale. How to do that?

Currently I have to change this manually every time I zoom in or zoom out.

[image]

Comment: What you should be google is [Scale range](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000008000000). Have your features in different shapefiles/feature classes and set different scale ranges on them (preferably not overlapping, but it's up to you).

Comment: Creating own shapefiles is an option but I would prefer some cute setting in ArcGIS interface for example  `Dynamic grid` which should adjust grid depends on map scale. Also I can write python scripts - so solving this problem with `arcpy` is an option too.

Comment: Looks like it is impossible at the moment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175016/changing-grid-interval-using-arcpy