# Turning off grid using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, export, grids-graticules

I work with 72 MXD's files, and i need to turn off the grid in order to export it without the grid.

I don't want to do it manually, neither using the "Tinytask" software, as mentioned in [Changing grid interval using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175016/changing-grid-interval-using-arcpy)

Is it possible to do this using python stand-alone code?

[image]

Comment: as @Ahmadhand said you can't access to a dataframe grid with arcpy.But if you export all of them in the PDF format with layers (In advanced tab of Export PDF select Export PDF Layers Only), You can uncheck graticules in the PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use arcpy to access grids defined for a data frame. However, the grids are exposed via an ArcGIS extension called [Production Mapping](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/what-is-production-mapping.htm) which according to the Esri Help page:

> The Esri Production Mapping extension streamlines your GIS data and
>   map production by providing tools that facilitate data creation,
>   maintenance, and validation, as well as tools for producing
>   high-quality cartographic products.

Alex Tereshenkov in his website explained more about how to [Access to ArcMap map document grid using Python and ArcObjects](https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2017/04/16/access-to-arcmap-map-document-grid/). You can have a look at it. It may help somehow or give you an idea on how to solve your problem.